# How to fix an app appearing twice in my application list

Tags: gnome, vlc, window-manager

I have VLC appearing twice on my app list using Gnome desktop on Ubuntu 20.04.I had VLC installed but the app wouldn't launch whenever I tried to. I decided to reinstall VLC,then VLC started appearing twice in my application list (one shortcut working fine and not the other).

Following MadcapJake advice on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/4fj8aa/why_do_some_of_my_applications_show_up_twice_in/), I typed:  `xprop WM_CLASS` and clicked on the vlc tab.

The result was :
`WM_CLASS(STRING) = "vlc", "vlc"`

Then I typed: `"vlc" StartupWMClass`

It resulted in:

```
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

filesystem stream error: cannot open file /home/nao/StartupWMClass (No such file or directory)
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION :**
There was another .desktop file related to VLC but not placed in the common application folder usually located in *usr/share/applications*
The problematic file was located into *var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications*

You can find the location of the problematic file by following [vanadium answer on this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1332197/1531266)

Once you know where it is, remove the app (VLC)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then you get into the repertory where the file is located by using :

```
cd /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications
```

(or any other path that your find command prompted you)

then you remove the file and reinstall :

```
sudo rm vlc_vlc.desktop 

sudo apt-get install vlc
```